# Gathering data from nginx and alerts users against a unique visitors quota

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, logging

I have a PoC that i am trying to do in which i am using nginx as a web server. What i am interested in is to alert users via email when a certain percent, say 90% of the allotted unique visitors quota, say 1000, has been reached.

Here is what i could think of:

- Enable acesslogs in nginx, run a cron on nginx host which runs at hourly intervals and gathers the unique IPs from the accesslog, put them into a database table(with REPLACE query). Another cron runs also on hourly interval, a little after the first cron, checks count of entries in that table and sends our alerts. On every new month, we truncate all entries in the unique_hits_ip_username table. Logs are rotated on weekly basis.

What i am concerned about:

- Running 2 crons on hourly basis might affect performance if userbase grows. If we increase the interval we might miss some landmarks such as say if on last run user's quota was 80%, and then on next run it gets to 110%. So we would be sending email for quota reaching 90% while its actually even more than the assigned one now.
- Database that contain unique ip log might grow to huge proportions.

Initially i planned both crons to be in php where i would read nginx's accesslog using file() function.

Do you have a better alternate in mind? or any tweaks to this approach? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the `access_log` directive to log to a Unix FIFO socket. Create a FIFO using `mknod /path/to/access.log` and try to configure the `access_log` directive for this FIFO object.

Now, you can write a script that will open the FIFO and read contents from it *in real time*, do your data manipulation, and insert the data you want into a database as you please.

This will remove the hourly disk IO bursts and give you far more responsive alerts.

One downside is that nginx *may* block on writing those access logs. (I doubt it, but it is a possibility.) You may wish to run your script at a slightly lower `nice` level than the web server just to ensure that you can always pull access log entries off the FIFO faster than they are being put on. (Lower `nice` values are *higher* priorities. See `nice(1)` for details.)

Comment: If such a scripts keeps running as a daemon, won't there be a performance hit as on each access nginx will send data to it and it will write to db? Or will nginx just throw data at FIFO device and get back to what it does best?

Comment: `nginx` will just throw data at the FIFO. Of course, the FIFO can hold at most 65536 unread bytes, so if your daemon pauses too long then `nginx` will either get a write error (if it used `O_NONBLOCK` `open(2)` flag) or block (if it forgot to use `O_NONBLOCK`) when writing to the pipe. I would hope your access-checking tool could run faster than reading files off the disk and sending them to clients: it just needs to do a bit of parsing, arithmetic, and kick off a notifier process of some sort.

Comment: That makes me consider python with threads or event for better results than php. Any comments on that?